# VBA: Go to first cell in a column containing certain value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to ask VBA to go to the first cell in column containing a certain value. For example in the table below,

[image]

I want Excel to go to column containing value 0.650833312 and return the first value in the column ("A"). Would the find function or cell address function be applicable?

Comment: You can use `Find()` for this.

Comment: @TimWilliams can you provide me with more details? I am relatively new to VBA.

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm

Comment: Is there a way to do so using a loop if I don't want to use the find function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will return value from column's first non empty cell value.

```
    Sub firstValueOfColumn()
    Dim dColumn As Long
    Cells.Select
    For Each tCell In Selection
        If tCell = 0.650833312 Then
            dColumn = tCell.Column
             tCell.Select
                If Cells(1, dColumn) = "" Then
                    MsgBox Cells(1, dColumn).End(xlDown).Value
                Else
                    MsgBox Cells(1, dColumn).Value
                End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

You can change msgbox or select cell as your own. I used that just to show result. Modify the sub as your need.